# XPath to exclude only a specific amount of html tags

Tags: xpath

```
<div class="page-main-content content-style">

<h1 class="title home-title">What’s On This Week <span class="">in the Best Sports Bar:</span></h1>

<div class="page-main-content-inner">
 <p class="">Now open and serving food from 7.00am till 1.00am every day</p>
 <p class="">Our kitchen stays open outside of these hours for special events.</p>
 <h2>Here’s the sport showing this week at biggest family friendly sports bar &amp; restaurant:</h2>
 
 <h2>BOXING</h2><p class="">Vergil Ortiz Jr v Michael McKinson, Sunday, 7th August @ 8.00am</p>
 <h2>UFC on ESPN: Santos vs. Hill</h2><p class="">Sunday, 7th August @ 9.00am (prelims @ 7.00am)<br class=""> Full main card replay @ 3.00pm on Sunday</p>
 <h2>MOTO GP</h2><p class="">Practice: Friday, 5th August @ 3.00pm and Saturday, 6th August @ 3.00pm<br class=""> Qualifying: Saturday, 6th August @ 6.00pm<br class=""> Races: Sunday, 7th August @ 4.30pm</p>
 <h2>CRICKET – WEST INDIES v INDIA</h2><p class="">2nd T20I: Monday, 1st August @ 9.30pm<br class=""> 3rd T20I: Tuesday, 2nd August @ 9.30pm<br class=""> 4th T20I: Saturday, 6th August @ 9.30pm<br class=""> 5th T20I: Sunday, 7th August @ 9.30pm</p>
 
 </div>
 
 </div>
```

I am trying to use XPATH to scrape all this content but I don't need the first two p tags and I don't need the first H2 tag either (Here’s the sport showing this week..)

So effectively I need to start scraping at BOXING which is the second H2 tag and then grab ALL content from there.

I've tried dozens of variations to exclude these:

```
//div[@class='page-main-content-inner']/*[not(self::p)]
```

But I cannot seem to get this to work. If I exclude p tags it excludes them all. Tried to limit this using stuff like `[position()>1]` but still cannot do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```xml
//div[@class='page-main-content-inner']/h2[1]/following-sibling::*
```

It finds your first `h2` and returns every sibling element that follows it:

```xml
<h2>BOXING</h2>
<p class="">Vergil Ortiz Jr v Michael McKinson, Sunday, 7th August @ 8.00am</p>
<h2>UFC on ESPN: Santos vs. Hill</h2>
<p class="">Sunday, 7th August @ 9.00am (prelims @ 7.00am)<br class=""/> Full main card replay @ 3.00pm on Sunday</p>
<h2>MOTO GP</h2>
<p class="">Practice: Friday, 5th August @ 3.00pm and Saturday, 6th August @ 3.00pm<br class=""/> Qualifying: Saturday, 6th August @ 6.00pm<br class=""/> Races: Sunday, 7th August @ 4.30pm</p>
<h2>CRICKET – WEST INDIES v INDIA</h2>
<p class="">2nd T20I: Monday, 1st August @ 9.30pm<br class=""/> 3rd T20I: Tuesday, 2nd August @ 9.30pm<br class=""/> 4th T20I: Saturday, 6th August @ 9.30pm<br class=""/> 5th T20I: Sunday, 7th August @ 9.30pm</p>
```

Comment: See https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#axes